# WCF is failed to consumed by Flex code

Tags: apache-flex, wcf, wsdl, flash-builder, disco

I have https://mysite/myservice.asmx which is consumed fine with Flashbuilder. When i ported it to https://mysite/myservice.svc, and generate proxy objects, flash proxy objects fails to call any operations. I guess, during web service call, operation contracts are got by https://mysite/myservice.asmx?op=myOp, but in WCF, https://mysite/myservice.svc?op=myOp gives disco file reference. Is there anything done it? Has anyone called WCF from Flex?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the WCF Config that you have setup, if you provide that I may be able to answer better, but for now try to access the WSDL from https://mysite/myservice.svc?wsdl